# node-webkit can't resolve path correctly on Windows

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm trying to build a simple node-webkit app on my Windows machine. Here's `main.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>node-webkit test</title>
</head>
<body>
hello world!
<script>
  var fileapi = require('../js/fileapi');
  var result = fileapi.add_res('../resources/file1.txt');
  var doc_hash = result.doc_hash, doc_info = result.doc_info;
  body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(doc_hash) + '\n' + JSON.stringfy(doc_info);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I zip my app and rename it `file-api.nw`. run `path\to\nw.exe file-api.nw`. Here's the node-webkit window I got:

[image]

It seems that node-webkit failed to find `../resources/file1.txt`. And what is the directory `C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\`?

my app dir tree is like this:

```
app
|
+--resources/
|  |
|  +--file1.txt
|
+--html/
   |
   +--main.html
```

Please forgive me if this is a basic question cause I'm new to node-webkit. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The root of the project is node-webkit's CWD.
>   The right path should be the next one.

```
var path = 'resources/file1.txt';
```

Comment: this did the trick and I've found it yesterday. Where are the quote from?

Comment: @laike9m What **quote** do you mean? Do you mean how I get the right **path** variable? It's a relative path question, the simplest way to solve is to dump the cwd with NW's API **process.cwd**, and check if the path is right or not.

Comment: No, I mean `The root of the project is node-webkit's CWD. The right path should be the next one`. or it's you who write this?

Comment: @laike9m I wrote it after I did some tests.